# Postman: How to execute Paypal CURL Request in Postman?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, postman

I'm able to get oAuth Request & Response

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

[image: enter code here]

But when I run it always gives 401 Unauthorized

How to execute below in Postman?

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
  -d '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://example.com/your_redirect_url.html",
    "cancel_url":"http://example.com/your_cancel_url.html"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First you need to paste the data part in Body:

```
{"intent": "sale",
 "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://example.com/your_redirect_url.html",
    "cancel_url": "http://example.com/your_cancel_url.html"

 },
 "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"

 },
 "transactions": [{
    "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD"

    }
    }]

}
```

then, you have to select raw and under Text select JSON(application/json)

For the authorization part, go to Headers:

```
[key:Content-Type, value:application/json]
[key:Authorization, value:Bearer YOUR_TOKEN]
```

then hit Send and you should get a 201 Created status

Answer (score 1):

From the image above it seems like you aren't sending data as JSON. On the paypal example it shows a JSON object for the data (-d). All you have to do is copy and paste it on the body and change the body to raw and then on the last column it will say text and an arrow just click on that and select JSON (application/json) this should do it.

Comment: Try to include lines of code and format your question to make it clear and legible.

Comment: @Masoud I think you need to comment on his question for him to see it.

Comment: "Question" was a typo. I meant your answer.

Comment: @Masoud the answer is a configuration not any code. I don't know how to post an image but all he has to do is change that configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have two questions:

**1:** You have to **get an access token**

as sais documentation: [image]

thats why you get an 401 Unauthorized, you have to configure an Authorization type OAuth2, and use your access token:[image]

**2:** I make a graphic example of this curl example on postman.

*Header:* [image]

*Body:* [image]

*Authorization:* don't forget configure token as you done for first question.

That's all!